# How to Cache image when src is some action which returns image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, image

There are lots of questions about how to force the browser to cache or not to cache any image. But, I am facing slightly different situation. In several places of my web page, I am using following code for the images.

```
<img title="<%= Html.Encode(Model.title)%>" 
  src="<%= Url.Action(MVC.FrontEnd.Actions.RetrieveImage(Model.SystemId))%>"/>
```

So, in the generated HTML it is like

```
<img title="blahblah" src="http://xyz.com/FrontEnd/Actions/RetrieveImage?imageId=X">
```

Where `X` is some integer. I have seen that though the browser (IE or Mozilla) caches images by default, it is not caching images generated by above method.

Is there any way I can tell browser to cache images of above type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you can set the Expires and MaxAge headers of the response. To simplify things, you can create a custom ActionFilter.

Here's a good guide in how to achieve this: [ASP.NET MVC Action Filter - Caching and Compression](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx)